# How to add SPL library into PhpStorm so that it recognises SPL Exceptions for PHPDoc

Tags: php, exception, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, spl

I noticed that PhpStorm doesn't recognise SPL Exceptions when I'm generating PHPDoc. How can I fix this? I don't know if my case is specific, I couldn't find anything about this on SO.

I'm using Symfony plugin if that info helps.

For example, if I throw new Exception it will generate `@throws \Exception` comment but if I do the same for any of the SPL exceptions it will just ignore it. It doesn't matter if I use `\Exception` or if I import the class. If I throw my custom exception that extends `Exception` it will also recognise it. I can open the RuntimeException class by ctrl+click, which means PhpStorm knows about the class but for some reason ignores it as exception.

I've also cloned and added phpstorm-stubs to my default stubs, didn't help. Picture shows how PhpStorm ignores the RuntimeException from the SPL but recognises the general Exception and displays warnings if the comment is missing.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for documentation like https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/04/configurable-unchecked-exceptions/?

Comment: Just a hint, I found that through less than a minute of using Google, and the search within PhpStorm's settings also highlighted the linked parts

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I found that as well however I dismissed it immediately because my problem was NotFoundHttpException (i just used RuntimeException as example in the picture). Now I dived into the NotFoundHttpException and found out that it extends HttpException which in turn extends RuntimeException. That's why it ignored it as well.

Comment: @TomislavCivcija Consider making it as an answer (you can accept it later) -- this will help others in similar situation.

Comment: @LazyOne I'm not sure what you mean. I see no option to make his comment as answer. Perhaps it's due to me having less than 15 reputation points (i can't even vote on answers).

Comment: There is a form down below where you can enter your text as an answer --- just like anybody else would enter.

Comment: Oh i meant that there's a possibility to convert his comment into answer and you wanted for me to do that!

Answer (score 1):

As Nico Haase pointed out, there is an option in PhpStorm that excludes SPL exceptions. It can be found [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2018/04/configurable-unchecked-exceptions/). Changing settings was the solution.

Just make sure that your exception does not extend one of those ignored exceptions (regardless of the depth of the hierarchy).

It would be good though if PhpStorm supported option for `exact/hierarchy` while ignoring exceptions.